# Filtering bad words

Tags: c#, string, filter, replace, blacklist

.Net version is 4.7.1 (no have third argument of string.Replace with ignorecase)

```
badwords = ["home", ...]
text = "Home, hhhome HOME, HOme Hhome1212, H o M e"
expected result: "****, hh**** ****, **** H****1212, *******"
```

It is necessary to ignore the case of the text while maintaining its original case

```
public string Filter(string text)
{
    foreach (var badword in _badwords)
    {
        text = text.Replace(badword, new string('*', badword.Length));
    }

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the overloads of `string.Replace` to see whether there's something there that can affect the string comparison in terms of case sensitivity?

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex replace.

Comment: string.Replace no have 3rd argument

Comment: @Nik  it [does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0#system-string-replace(system-string-system-string-system-stringcomparison)). There are 4 overloads and 2 allow specifying case-insensitive replacements

Comment: I have only string.Replace (string oldValue, string newValue) and string.Replace (char oldValue, char newValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the third argument to the `string.Replace` method and specify it as `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.